# WPF Make StackPanel in Horizontal Orientation

Tags: c#, wpf, stackpanel

My xaml code is as follows

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TopRulerElementViewModel}">
            <Ellipse Width="5" Height="5">
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Black"/>
                </Ellipse.Fill>
            </Ellipse>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="200" Width="500">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TopRulerElements}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

My code in ViewModel is like this

```
    private ObservableCollection<TopRulerElementViewModel> _TopRulerElements;

    public ObservableCollection<TopRulerElementViewModel> TopRulerElements
    {
        get { return _TopRulerElements; }
        set
        {
            _TopRulerElements = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("TopRulerElements");
        }
    }
```

But when I run my application. All the Ellipse are shown vertically. 
How can I make the Ellipse shown horizontally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not do like that, you need to set itemspanel property of control to specify how the items should be aligned. try the follwing code.

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TopRulerElementViewModel}">
                <Ellipse Width="5" Height="5">
                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Black"/>
                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                </Ellipse>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TopRulerElements}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="200" Width="500"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer. The Ellipse can be shown vertically when making a small change in xaml code.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="200" Width="500">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TopRulerElements}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Add ItemsPanel, then it works